# MYSQL: Synax Error on SELECT...INTO OUTFILE

Tags: mysql, into-outfile

I keep getting a syntax error when attempting to Select Into Output File (near the filename): (“ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ‘/path/file’ FIELDS TERMINATED at line 3”)

Here is the query:

```
SELECT Field
FROM Table
INTO OUTFILE ‘/path/test.csv’
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘,’
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY “”
LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\n’
;
```

I have tried “INTO” before/after FROM, numerous paths (and no path), removed the Terminated/Enclosed, ensured the query runs to print  to Shell (is valid), ensured user (root) has *.* File privileges granted, ensured secure_file_priv = “”, single v double quotes, etc…

While I have reviewed many pages on may sites dealing with what appear to be variations of the issue, I have found nothing that works.  It is obviously some very simple error (privileges of some sort?), but I am stumped.

I am using MYSQL 5.7.18 on MAC OS X via Terminal.  Thanks in advance.

Added: Dealing with 20mm+ rows and open to other ways to get the output to a file as copy/paste from Shell not a realistic option of course.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html

Comment: You need single quotes for the strings (`'`).  Your single quote character doesn't quite look right.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Thanks, I understand and agree.  Unfortunately that was a typo in original post when generalizing the query.  To be clear, same issue above using: SELECT Field
FROM Table
INTO OUTFILE “~/var/test.csv”
FIELDS TERMINATED BY “,”
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY “”
LINES TERMINATED BY “\n”
;

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you are using forward tick and back tick in your syntax (did you cut and paste from a website/tutorial?)

Instead of ‘/path/test.csv’ try '/path/test.csv'

Try this out (I'm also using MySQL on OSX)

```
mysql> create table foo (a varchar(10));
mysql> insert into foo values ('a');
mysql> insert into foo values ('b');
```

Finally,

```
mysql> SELECT a FROM foo INTO OUTFILE "~/tmp/test.csv" FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY "" LINES TERMINATED BY "\n" ;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

I used double quotes to avoid confusion about ticks.

Comment: I simply typed it, rather the cut/paste.  I have just tried using all forward ticks and then using all backward ticks and received the same error (same as original) each time.  I had not considered that as a possibility though, thanks.

Comment: I re-read original post and see the basis for the Answer provided above.  To be clear, I have tried with the below syntax and received same error as noted in the original post:

SELECT Field
FROM Table
INTO OUTFILE ‘~/tmp/test.csv’
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘,’
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY “”
LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\n’
;

Comment: Executing the above ("foo"), I did actually receive a different error: (ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file "/var/empty/tmp/test.csv"  (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)).  I changed the ("foo") path to '~/var/filename' and appeared to run, but is actually just in "SLEEP" state although, no error it seems to work.  However, I went back to my original query using "~/var/filename" and still receive original error (now using double-quotes for all).

Comment: I noticed there was no "tmp" folder in "var/empty/" so I created one, permissioned all users, and the Select Into you scripted worked.  However, I can not replicate this with other queries.  Moreover, I  deleted test.csv, opened new Shell and ran identical "foo" query and can not replicate the success from before (re-run with test2 failed).  It appears (from the error message 2 comments above and the single success) my configuration needs to write to /var/empty/tmp and that is likely the best "Answer" so far.  No clue how to explain the seemingly random result however.

Comment: Resolved.  I pasted my text (from TextEdit) into WorkBench and retyped quotes then pasted back into Shell and consistently working now (also works fine when typing direct into Shell).  Summarizing Answers: I appear to be configured to write to var/empty/tmp (fine for me) and my characters were somehow being manipulated between TextEdit and Shell.  Thanks everyone for helping me to walk through these simple items.

Comment: If you could accept the answer, that would be appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the pair of double quotes seem to be the issue.
try

```
SELECT Field
FROM Table
INTO OUTFILE ‘/path/test.csv’
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘,’
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\n’
;
```

Comment: I receive the same error when using single quotes for all 3 instances.  Thanks.